# git not receiving post commit results from svn server

Tags: git, svn, hook, git-svn, svn-hooks

I'm using git to commit to an svn server, which has a post commit hook. This post commit hook is supposed to return some text to the client. The hook works fine when I use pure svn, but git svn does not display the text.

Googling around, I have been unable to find any details regarding issues with git-svn integration. Has anyone else run into this problem, and if so, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because git-svn is using the original `get_commit_editor()` interface that only passes in the new revision number, author, and commit date.  `get_commit_editor2()` provides access to the error message, but it doesn't appear to be a simple change since it stopped passing in the other items as individual arguments and provides a structure now.

Perhaps you can report the issue to the [git mailing list](http://git-scm.com/community), and they can help fix it.  They are a friendly and helpful community.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the mailing list. I'll send them a bug report.